# PLTE chunk missing from a non-corrupt PNG file

Tags: opengl, png, glut

I am making a PNG importer for use in GLUT and OpenGL projects.  When I open a PNG file in a hex editor or reference this image:

http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/1/17/PNG-Gradient_hex.png

the PLTE chunk cannot be seen.  How do I know where it is?  Does it follow directly after processing IHDR?

Comment: how about looking this up for yourself?

Comment: The PLTE must come after IHDR and before the first IDAT chunk. Read here. http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#5ChunkOrdering

This tool can be useful: http://entropymine.com/jason/tweakpng/

Comment: PLTE is optional as mentioned here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Network_Graphics

Answer (score 1):

This is not a paletted image, so there is no need for a PLTE chunk. From [the PNG Reference](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html#C.IHDR):

```
Color    Allowed    Interpretation
Type     Bit Depths
2        8/16       Each pixel is an R,G,B triple.
```

Comment: Ok.  The reason for me posting this question was that because the PLTE is a critical chunk but I could not find it when I looked into my image; its absence from my PNG file confused me.

Comment: According to the reference, a critical chunk is one that "[a]ll implementations must understand and successfully render" ([4.1](http://www.w3.org/TR/PNG-Chunks.html#C.Critical-chunks)). Right after that, the reference lists the *minimal contents* of a "valid PNG image" :)